# Search one file to see if it contains information from another file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

So I have two files. The first is `unip.txt` and the second is `ipex.txt` and each file contains IP addresses.

```
unip.txt                                            ipex.txt

49.235.113.205                                      51.15.134.103
50.115.166.136                                      148.70.23.131
51.15.70.104                                        151.141.0.0
51.15.87.74                                         97.89.32.238
51.15.134.103
146.148.13.9
148.70.23.131
148.72.212.161
148.216.29.46
149.56.141.193
```

I'm trying to figure out how to basically search the `unip.txt` file to see if it contains any IP from the `ipex.txt` file. I imagine that it would be a loop to search through every line but after searching online for a long time I can't find anything useful. Any help would be useful. I apologize for anything that makes no sense, english is my second language.

Comment: This is a perfect use case for the `join` command or the `comm` command.

Comment: From the dup, `grep -F -f ipex.txt unip.txt` might work, although may be slow with huge files.